# Homogeneity of Variance Test for RCB Design in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following query, I want to apply a test for homogeneity of variances for a completely random design with blocks.
I tried levene but it is not acceptable with 2 factors

```r
library(car)
library(tibble)

tb = tibble("treat" = factor(x = rep(1:3,c(4,4,4) ),
                             labels = c("disen 1","disen 2","disen 3")),
            "bloque" = factor(x = c(rep(1:4,3)),
                              labels = c("NE","NW","SE","SW")),
            "value" = c(250,350,219,375,
                        400,525,390,580,
                        275,340,200,310))
```

here I apply the levene test

```r
leveneTest(value ~ treat*bloque,tb) # no show result
```

is there any other statistical test for homogeneity of variances for RCBD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only 1 observation per combination of groups:

```
table(tb$treat,tb$bloque)
         
          NE NW SE SW
  disen 1  1  1  1  1
  disen 2  1  1  1  1
  disen 3  1  1  1  1
```

You cannot calculate variance with n=1 (i.e the best fit is the single value).

If you have a data with n>1 for at least 1 group, it works:

```
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$gear = factor(mtcars$gear)

with(mtcars,table(gear,cyl))
    cyl
gear  4  6  8
   3  1  2 12
   4  8  4  0
   5  2  1  2

leveneTest(mpg ~ gear*cyl,mtcars)

Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
      Df F value  Pr(>F)  
group  7  2.1926 0.07172 .
      24                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: perfect, tank you